# API Gateway error (ValidationException: ExpressionAttributeValues must not be empty) when trying to update DynamoDB entry

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am new to AWS and am trying to set up the back end for my buddy's website.  I am able to 'get' entries from my database (called 'isThrowingTable') but am unable to 'put' updates into it.  I run a Request Body as seen in the picture/code below and I get a response body (error) as seen in the pic/code (see the lambda function line 28 to see how that response is created, I added stuff to debug it)

[API Gateway 'Request Body' 'Resources' and 'ErrorMessage'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCHOv.png)

```html
ERROR: ValidationException: ExpressionAttributeValues must not be empty Unable to put product: event.body {
    "dataName": "throwingStatus",
    "updatedInfo": false
} into params {"TableName":"isThrowingTable","Key":{},"UpdateExpression":"set info = :info","ExpressionAttributeValues":{},"ReturnValues":"UPDATED_NEW"} dataName: undefined updatedInfo undefined
```

```html
{
    "dataName": "throwingStatus",
    "updatedInfo": false
}
```

This is the lambda that is kicked off from the Gateway Test

```html
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  let responseBody = "";
  let statusCode = 0;
  
  //const { dataName, updatedInfo } = JSON.parse((event.body)); //SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 1
    const dataName = event.body.dataName
    const updatedInfo = event.body.updatedInfo
   var params = {
    TableName: "isThrowingTable",
    Key: {
      id: dataName
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set info = :info",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":info": updatedInfo
    },
    ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
  };

  try {
    const data = await documentClient.update(params).promise();
    responseBody = JSON.stringify(data);
    statusCode = 201;
  } catch(err) {
    responseBody = `ERROR: ${err} Unable to put product: event.body ${event.body} into params ${JSON.stringify(params)} dataName: ${dataName} updatedInfo ${updatedInfo}`;
    statusCode = 403;
  }

  return {
    statusCode: statusCode,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "access-control-allow-origin": "*"
    },
    body: responseBody
  };
};
```

As you can see in the error message, params.Key and params.ExpressionAttributeValues are not set and I'm not sure why.  In the print out of event.body you can see dataName (the id of the item in the database) and updatedInfo are present but trying to grab it results in 'undefined'.  I am hoping for a fix and also to learn why this is happening.

Comment: Did you try logging `updateInfo` immediately after its set? Does event body need parsing?

Comment: I did, it runs into the same error.  I need to get the information from the event body

Comment: Looks like it might not be parsed properly. When you log `event.body ${event.body}` it really should trace out `event.body [object Object]` if it was an object, so it looks like event.body is a string that need parsing. Did JSON.parse really throw an error? (you have an unnecessary pair of extra brackets in the parse too)

Comment: Yeah it throws the error "Response:
{
  "errorType": "SyntaxError",
  "errorMessage": "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1",
  "trace": [
    "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1",
    "    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:9:42)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
  ]
}
WITH "const { dataName, updatedInfo } = JSON.parse(event.body);
    // const dataName = event.body.dataName
    // const updatedInfo = event.body.updatedInfo"

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to insert code in comments, new to StackOverflow as well

Comment: I also tried "const { dataName, updatedInfo } = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.body));" (which is why there were extra brackets in there) and that fixed the error I commented on above, but not the problem I described in this StackOverflow post

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your event.body otherwise updatedinfo will be undefined.
Try this

```
const {updatedInfo} = JSON.parse(event.body)
var params = {
TableName: "isThrowingTable",
Key: {
  id: dataName
},
UpdateExpression: "set info = :info",
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":info": updatedInfo
},
ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
```

};

That worked for me.